# Horizontal scroll container with text not working

Tags: html, css

How do I get my container to scroll horizontally? For some reason it is not working. I have text in my container and have seen other recommendations on Stackoverflow to use the "white-space: nowrap;" attribute in css, but that does not produce the expected outcome here. It causes the text in the div to display in one long line and scroll horizontally which is NOT what I want.

I would like the divs in the container to scroll horizontally when the container overflows for smaller screen widths. This is what I have now for code...

```css
.twitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}
.tweets {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,30%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="twitter">
    <div class="tweets">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
        <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
        <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
        <p>A significant rule to follow and perhaps one of the most effective methods in getting your property booked more often is getting it noticed...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tweets">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
        <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
        <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
        <p>Maintaining a high guest rating for your Airbnb business can boost conversions and make you appear as a favorable company in the...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tweets">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
        <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
        <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
        <p>A significant rule to follow and perhaps one of the most effective methods in getting your property booked more often is getting it noticed!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You _want_ one long line. What else would there be to scroll?

Comment: The expected behavior is to have the the container scroll horizontally so you could see all of the divs inside of the container. I do not want the text to scroll, I want the "tweets" to scroll.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't at all clear. Well, the same solution should apply.

Comment: My apologies there, I realized that and edited it after I re-read the question. I've just tested the above code in a separate html file and it works just fine. Looks like something in my current file is overwriting the css. I'll dig into it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If you want your paragraph containing text to scroll you have to select it and add `overflow-x:scroll` together with `text-wrap: nowrap`.

```css
.twitter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    /* overflow-x: scroll; */
    gap: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
  }
  .tweets {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,30%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15rem;
  }

.twitter .tweets p{
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="twitter">
        <div class="tweets">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
            <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
            <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
            <p>A significant rule to follow and perhaps one of the most effective methods in getting your property booked more often is getting it noticed...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tweets">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
            <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
            <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
            <p>Maintaining a high guest rating for your Airbnb business can boost conversions and make you appear as a favorable company in the...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tweets">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ADCreHeprrwtm57aVP2xK6Nl-P1wibmjfvnE9yKHd7KYL-yc7ZkeC-O6gVrz4429dUoL2uqo8ERB9nqPOiiHSTnrK_Z4dg_sU3cA4DGwGXdj8-UbVveZu4-K=w2400" alt="Image cannot be displayed." id="t-logo">
            <h2>Hibbert Luxury Essentials <img id="badges" src="images/badge.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed."></h2>
            <h3>@hibbertluxuryessentials</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, nihil? Non dolorem repellendus omnis ullam iure illum quam neque inventore!A significant rule to follow and perhaps one of the most effective methods in getting your property booked more often is getting it noticed!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I want the divs in the container to scroll horizontally when they overflow on the page for smaller device widths, not just the text itself. How do I achieve this?